# Creation working locally, but not on Heroku. ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

Users can create guides only when they're logged in.

When I click on the 'New Guide' link, this is what Heroku's log puts out:

```
2013-12-30T20:28:37.826032+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
```

GuidesController:

```
class GuidesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_guide, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /guides
  # GET /guides.json
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @guides = Guide.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @guides = Guide.all
    end

  end

  # GET /guides/1
  # GET /guides/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /guides/new
  def new
    @guide = current_user.guides.build(guide_params)
  end

  # GET /guides/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /guides
  # POST /guides.json
  def create
    @guide = current_user.guides.build(guide_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @guide.save
        format.html { redirect_to @guide, notice: 'Guide was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @guide }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @guide.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /guides/1
  # PATCH/PUT /guides/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @guide.update(guide_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @guide, notice: 'Guide was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @guide.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /guides/1
  # DELETE /guides/1.json
  def destroy
    @guide.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to guides_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_guide
      @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def guide_params
      params.require(:guide).permit(:title, :author, :description, :link, :tag_list) if params[:guide]
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any error? Please provide the details to help you debugging the issue.

Comment: Oh yes. How could I forget... Silly.

Comment: Have you done this `heroku run rake:db migrate`

Comment: @bjhaid - Yes I have.

Comment: @DylanRichards anymore stack trace??

Comment: What are you using for User Authentication? Also is there anything after this error in the logs? It ends in a colon, as if it lists more stack trace after that error.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your `new` action

```
def new
  @guide = current_user.guides.build(guide_params)
end
```

Why? The new action should just return the form to the browser to create a new guide. You repeat this in your `create` action, where it should be.

Also your `index` has this:

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @guides = Guide.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @guides = Guide.all
  end
end
```

You should probably be using `guide_params[:tag]` since the `:tag` is being returned by the browser.

**EDIT** I see you are using `[:tag_list]` in your whitelist.  I assume you are handing that somewhere else? Have you tested the ability to do an `index` action with a tag defined? I think the only place you want to use bare `params[:xxxx]` is in a private method.